# plt.axvline pierce through a cumulative histogram curve

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I draw a histogram using numpy and matplotlib.pyplot, and then plot vertical lines at certain x-values intersecting the cumulative curve of the histogram.

[image]

However, the problem encountered is that the vertical lines, drawn using plt.axvline, are extending beyond the cumulative curve, rather than stopping at the intersection points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(loc=350, scale=100, size=10000)

hist, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=len(data), cumulative=True, density=True)

# Find the intersections of the x-axis with the cumulative curve
x_values = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
y_values = np.interp(x_values, bins[:-1], hist)

# Plot vertical lines at the intersections
for x, y in zip(x_values, y_values):
    plt.axvline(x=x, ymin=0, ymax=y, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, color='red', s=50)
```

The axvlines pierce through the curve.
What confuse most is, when I change `plt.axvline` to `plt.vlines`, it works perfectly as:

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.normal(loc=350, scale=100, size=1000)

hist, bins, patches = plt.hist(data, bins=len(data), cumulative=True, density=True)
''
# Find the intersections of the x-axis with the cumulative curve
x_values = [200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
y_values = np.interp(x_values, bins[:-1], hist)

# Plot vertical lines at the intersections
plt.vlines(x=x_values, ymin=0, ymax=y_values, color='r', linestyle='-',lw=0.8)
plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, color='red', s=50)
```

how can I get the vertical lines to stop exactly at the cumulative curve when applying plt.axvline?

Comment: Don't use `axvline`, use `vlines`. A careful read of the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html), specifically the `ymin` and `ymax` parameters, should convince you.

Comment: If `vlines` works, why are you trying to use `axvline`?

Comment: Well, `plt.axvline()` considers the y-axis in "axes coordinates". These are 0 at the bottom of the plot and 1 at the top.  You seem to expect "data coordinates", for which `plt.vlines()` would be appropriate. See [the transforms tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) for more information about coordinate systems in matplotlib.

Comment: @jared sometime will use it for single line which does not specify both min and max every time, so be aware of its limits might help.

Comment: I'm only talking about this specific case.